# Why is it only showing 2 out of the 3 arrays?

Tags: php, xml, arrays, for-loop

I'm not sure why this is happening. Here is my XML:

```
<ResultSet>
<chats>
    <chat>
        <messages>
            <sms>
                <from>Bisma Iqbal</from>
                <msg>Hi</msg>
                <sent>1311612055</sent>
            </sms>
            <sms>
                <from>Bisma Iqbal</from>
                <msg>Hi</msg>
                <sent>1311612068</sent>
            </sms>
            <sms>
                <from>Bisma Iqbal</from>
                <msg>Hi</msg>
                <sent>1311612074</sent>
            </sms>
            <sms>
                <from>Bisma Iqbal</from>
                <msg>Hi</msg>
                <sent>1311612186</sent>
            </sms>
        </messages>
        <contact>Bisma Iqbal</contact>
    </chat>
    <chat>
        <messages>
            <sms>
                <from>Javaid Iqbal</from>
                <msg>this is the first message</msg>
                <sent>1311612055</sent>
            </sms>
            <sms>
                <from>Javaid Iqbal</from>
                <msg>this is the second message</msg>
                <sent>1311612055</sent>
            </sms>
        </messages>
        <contact>Javaid Iqbal</contact>
    </chat>
    <chat>
        <messages>
            <sms>
                <from>Ankur Shahi</from>
                <msg>Wanna play dawg at 7:15</msg>
                <sent>1311632708</sent>
            </sms>
            <sms>
                <from>Ankur Shahi</from>
                <msg>Wanna play dawg at 7:15</msg>
                <sent>1311632708</sent>
            </sms>
            <sms>
                <from>Ankur Shahi</from>
                <msg>Wanna play dawg at 7:15</msg>
                <sent>1311632708</sent>
            </sms>
        </messages>
        <contact>Ankur Shahi</contact>
    </chat>
</chats>
</ResultSet>
```

Now, here is my code:

```
require_once('global.php');
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=1");
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchObject();
$string = $result->chats;
$chats = GBA($string, "<chat>", "</chat>"); //the XML I showed you

for($i = 0, $size = count($chats); $i < $size; ++$i) {
//for every chat:
    $all_sms = GBA($chats[$i], "<sms>", "</sms>");
    $name = GB($chats[$i], "<contact>", "</contact>");
    echo "<center><table border='1' cellpadding='5'><tr><td colspan='3' align='center'>SMS Chat with <i>{$name}</i></td></tr><tr><th>From</th><th>Message</th><th>Sent</th></tr>";

    for($j = 0, $size = count($all_sms); $j < $size; ++$j) {
    //for every sms in each chat
            $from = GB($all_sms[$j], "<from>", "</from>");
            $msg = GB($all_sms[$j], "<msg>", "</msg>");
            $sent = time_since(GB($all_sms[$j], "<sent>", "</sent>"));
            echo "<tr><td>{$from}</td><td>{$msg}</td><td>Sent: {$sent}   </td></tr>";
        }
    echo "</table><br /><br /></center>";
}
```

As you can see, everything looks fine but it only shows the first 2 tables, not the third! I have a debugged a lot to no conclusion.

Comment: GB is a function that gets the string between two other strings. GBA is a funciton that gets the string between two other strings, but searches the whole string and returns an array. Getbetween and GetbetweenAll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the inner loop you reassign $size. The second chat group of sms has only 2 entries which causes the outer loop to terminate since $size = 2 and $i = 2.  Jon Martin's suggestion appears to work for your specific data but will fail in general case.

I suggest

```
for($j = 0, $jsize = count($all_sms); $j < $jsize; ++$j) {
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You used `$size` in the outer loop, and `$size` in the inner loop.

PHP has no block scope, so this is *the same variable*. As it changes in the inner loop, you're messing up your outer loop.

Pick a different name for the variable in the inner loop.